# How to scroll the Scrollbox by .Perform() or SendMessage if Scrollbar.visible := False?

Tags: delphi, sendmessage, tscrollbox

I have observed that when you hide the Horizontal Scrollbar, it will not scroll when using the

`sbxStudyBtnHolder.Perform(WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);`

how can we make it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can still scroll it using `ScrollBy`:

```
ScrollBox1.ScrollBy(-8, 0);
```

or

```
ScrollBox1.ScrollBy(-ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Increment, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't be back scrolling after this.
Try this:

```
ScrollBox1.ScrollInView(panel[n]);
```

`panel[n]` is the TControl you like to see.